# What does $F'$ and $F''$ mean?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, notation, taylor-expansion

I'm trying to learn what a Taylor series is, [This is the equation I'm looking at](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TaylorSeries.html) and I know 0 calculus. I have been told that $F'(x)$ is a derivative but what does $F''(x)$ mean?

Comment: shouldn't it be "what *do* $F'$ and $F''$ mean?"

Comment: What do you mean? that's what I wrote.

Comment: @LorenMeehan : No, you used a double quote. The comment used two single quotes, which could have been a hint that it's more like (F')'  :)

Comment: oh, ok. thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @vsz I italicized "do" for a reason...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$f''$ denotes the second derivative of $f$; that is to say, it is the derivative of the derivative of $f$.

Comment: Thanks! I feel quite stupid now that I didn't figure that myself.

Comment: Don't beat yourself up over it, I can understand how it might happen for your first foray into calculus. A good chunk of the notation can be a bit unintuitive at times. :p